# Multiple network connections, where does traffic get routed through?

Tags: networking, network-manager

My thinkpad has two network interfaces, one wired and one wireless. Both interfaces can be connected to a router which in turn is connected to the Internet.

If both interfaces are connected, are both interfaces used simultaneously or just one at a time. How can I tell which interface is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I activated my wired eth0 and wifi eth2 with network manager (both dhcp):

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 eth2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

`tcpdump -n -i eth0` shows traffic, while `tcpdump -n -i eth2` doesn't.

So let's try to reorder the interfaces in the routing table:

```
sudo route del -net 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2
sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2
sudo route -n add default gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth2
```

Now the routing table is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

now tcpdump shows all the traffic going through the eth2 interface.

Answer (score 6):

Network interfaces have a "metric" value. If multiple interfaces can reach to the gateway, the one with the smallest metric will be used.

You can try typing `netstat -r` at the command line to have a look at that.
`ifconfig` will give the metric for each interface as well.

Comment: +1 What decides the metric value? The device itself, configuration, or something else entirely?

Comment: +1 Typing ifconfig in my case (eth0 disconnected, wlan0 connected) given Metric:1 for all interfaces. How is this metric value to be interpreted ?

Comment: @koushik Think of metric as the cost to send traffic for that rule. It will try to send it the way that costs the least.